# How to detect if the phone is used outside of my app?

Tags: android, ios, flutter

I want to detect if the phone is used outside of my app, for both Android and iOS.

I need to be able to differentiate between these events:

1. The app is paused because the screen gets locked -> in this case, I dont want to do anything.
2. The app is paused for any other reason -> in this case, I want to send a notification to the user.

In both these cases, the "didChangeAppLifecycleState" returns the states "inactive" and then "paused" on my iPhone.

I know its possible because both the Forest app (https://www.forestapp.cc) and the Hold app (https://www.hold.app) does this.